# Quicksight change column name table

Tags: amazon-quicksight

How do I change the column name on a quicksight visual?  At the minute the name is matching to the fieldname from the dataset.

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on visual then format visual then I was able to change the column names